# Can't build ExtJs app

Tags: javascript, extjs

> [ERR] BUILD FAILED [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: Cannot
>   find file: C:\Users\cle1394\D ocuments\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Intake\extjs\build\temp\production\RateMana
>   gement\sencha-compiler\app\full-page-master-bundle.js

It says it can't find the file; however when I copy and paste the path to that exact file, I can confirm that it DOES exist.  So, why isn't Sencha recognizing it, and more importantly, why can't I build my app?

I have installed the Sencha CMD and I ran this command:

`cd C:\Users\cle1394\D ocuments\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Intake\extjs`

Then, I ran this:

`sencha app build`

Which returned the error above.

Note:  I installed Sencha CMD and Ruby and my Path variable has `C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Users\cle1394\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.2.67;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I pulled this project down from TFS so everything was readonly. Once I cleared the readonly flag from the entire app directory, everything was fine.